# How to integrate Deep Sort with my tensorflow object detection model?

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection, tracking

I took the pretrained fast r-cnn tensorflow model and did transfer learning on it to train it for my specific use case (football matches). Now, i want to integrate it with deep sort to be able to track football players through a football match video. But, im struggling to make this work as the tutorials online are very confusing and don't explain the code so i can adapt it for my model.

so lets just say i have my pretrained model files: checkpoint / ckpt-0.data-00000-of-00001 / ckpt-0.index. How can i now proceed to implement deep sort with it?